# Quartz 2D : draw on a view without subclassing it?

Tags: ios, xcode, quartz-2d

Can I get the context of a view with out subclassing it?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't a UIView delegate that handles drawing, so no, to my knowledge you can't. certainly not in a way that is easier than just subclassing UIView.